# How find one msg to multi request response Ajax Data done

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hell I send 3 request in ajax, my webservice will be return me 3 success message
I just like to show one.

Exemple:

```
.done(function(shipdata) {
  var ship = $(shipdata);
  var msgerror = ship.filter('#alert');
  if (msgerror == "INVALID_SHIPTO_TOWN") {
        $("#ship-modal-data p").append("code postal, ville destinataire est erronée.");      
      };

  this rum 3, I like just show 1 
     code postal, ville destinataire est erronée.
     code postal, ville destinataire est erronée.
     code postal, ville destinataire est erronée.
```

Thank u to helpe me

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery's [**$.when()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
$.when(ajax1, ajax2, ajax3).done(function(resp1, resp2, resp3){
    //which response do you want? This will fire when all 3 ajax calls have completed
    console.log(resp3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`append` will add your message to the `p`tag for each response, so it will be added 3 times if 3 errors.

Use the `text` function to overwrite `p` content instead and you'll have a single message at the end:

```
$("#ship-modal-data p").text("code postal, ville destinataire est erronée.");
```

Comment: But if he uses `.done()` on 3 calls separately, then he will get 3 messages, `this rum 3 or I like just show 1` indicates to me he just wants to show one message once all 3 responses have completed.

Comment: That's why I suggested using `text` function as it will replace the content of `p` evry time `done()` is called.

Comment: Yes I like juste one msg if 3 response have completed, I will post all my code look here

Comment: @momo then you should use `$.when()`, just like I said.

Answer (score 0):

I use this methode

```
var myEnum = {
     FT: 'FT',
     FK: 'FKS',
     PTT : 'PTTS'
}
$.each( myEnum, function(key, value) {
  var postdata = $('#form_id').serializeArray();
  postdata.push({name: 'carrier', 'value': value});
  postdata.push({name: 'submit', 'value': true});
  //console.log(postdata);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "offreship.php",
        data:postdata
        }.done(function(shipdata) {
        var ship = $(shipdata);
         var msgerror = ship.filter('#alert');
       if (msgerror == "INVALID_SHIPTO_TOWN") {
          $("#ship-modal-data p").append("code postal, ville destinataire est erronée.");      
         };
```

this rum 3 or I like just show 1 
     code postal, ville destinataire est erronée.
     code postal, ville destinataire est erronée.
     code postal, ville destinataire est erronée.
It work well just I like to show 1 msg for all

Comment: You should include this update in your question and not post it as an answer.